# Looking to create a switch box for multiple audio aux inputs

Tags: switches, audio, switching

I'm looking to create a circuit that will switch a 3.5mm audio input between 3 or more sources using multiple switches. I've made a quick schematic to try to explain my idea, but I'm fairly sure this won't work as the audio will use the ground of which ever input is switched on.

Thanks for the help & sorry for the beginner question.

[image: My Schematic - Multiple inputs on the left and output on the right]

Answer (score 1):

You should tie all the ground together, then switch the audio lines (right, left), not the other way around.

Comment: I would stress the 'should' into a 'must'. OP circuit can misbehave in a number of funny ways. If you need to control everything with buttons use double SPST relays, possibly NO ones.

Comment: Ah okay, so use DPST switches to turn on an off both the left and right signals - more like this (can't find the DPST schematic so imagination is required)? http://imgur.com/a/rabyH

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6besB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The switch circuit.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A suitable switch from CK.*

The 12-position rotary switches are available in configurations of 1 x 12-way, 2 x 6-way, 3 x 4-way, 4 x 3-way or 6 x 2-way. Any except the first or last will do the job you require.

[image]

*Figure 3. Switch pattern options.*

The switches feature an adjustable stop to restrict number
of positions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mr Lathrop's answer:
If OP doesn't want some mechanical switching, he/she can go for an analog multiplexer. A multiplexer simply a device that allows the user to select an input from different inputs and route it to one (or more) output(s).